# Где искать установленных библиотек python в ос linux (Mint если это имеет значение)?

Tags: python-3.x

Всем по пятьки!
Я обращаюсь самым глупым вопросом на мой взгляд но, я установил библиотеку speech_recognition (далее sr), и не могу найти ее в системе, знаю что библиотеки находятся в /usr/lib/... но там sr'a нет, подскажите пожалуйста где еще можно искать...

кстати установил sr через pip3

Comment: Просто используйте виртуальное окружение, и устанавливайте зависимости туда, тогда не нужно будет искать.

Comment: Ну например в `~/.local/lib/` (но лучше использовать виртуальное окружение, да)

Comment: баллиин! спасибо огромное! под носом был оказывается